# Find the radius of three equal circles, with radius $r$, inscribed in a rectangle.

Tags: euclidean-geometry

How can we find the radius of the small circles with the same given radius $r$. Three equal circles, with radius $r$, are inscribed in a rectangle in a way only one of them touches the others two, as the figure indicates. The circles centres form an isosceles triangle, is there any theorem can help in finding the value of $r$? Thanks for your help.
[image]

Comment: The larger circle has radius 25/3, if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me how did you get that value, if you don't mind?

Comment: What is that whiet curve that goes from D to C?  We are not told it is circle.  I think there are many ways to do this if we don't know it is a circle.  (It's be three circles inscribed in a rectangle of height $6$ and unknown width)

Comment: @BenW In an earlier comment you said the right circle would be describe by $(x-r-7/3)^2+(y-r-7/3)^2=r^2$ , which implies the center is on the $y = x$ diagonal. I think this is what went wrong. How did you get that?

Comment: "The width is the green 16 as marked on top. "  But if you don't know what the white curve is, the 16 doesn't matter.  We could have the white curve stretch out to $200$.  Or have it drop down to a make the rectangle shorter.  In fact the circles are *not* inscribed in the rectangle.  They are inscribed in the white curve.

Comment: If the undefined arc belongs to a circle, then the quantity $$\frac13\sqrt{\frac{1250\phi}{1080}-\frac{56}{π}},$$ where $\phi<90$ and $\sin \phi=0.96,$ and $\phi$ in degrees, gives an upper bound on $r.$ By other considerations we may obtain a lower bound of $3/2$ on $r,$ so that we have an estimate of $r.$

Answer (score 3):

**Assume** it is a big circle with radius $R$ that the smaller circles are tangent to. As fleablood commented, if that white arc is not circular (while maintaining mirror symmetry, as per the isosceles requirement) then the answer would be different.

Note that the given lengths of the "frame" forms the $3$-$4$-$5$ Pythagorean triple.

In the diagram below, the center of the big circle, point $O$, can be found by the perpendicular bisector of $\overline{PC}$ which length is $|PC|=10$.

With the similarity $\triangle PBC \sim \triangle OPQ~$ we have
$$R = |PO| = |PQ| \cdot\frac{|PC|}{|BC|} = |PQ| \cdot\frac53 = \frac{25}3$$
[image]

Next, please consult the diagram below to obtain the desired small circle radius $r$.

Observe that the height is related to the small radius:

$$ |BC| = |PF|+|FJ|+|EH| = 2r + |FJ|~,$$

then for $|FJ|$, from the similarity $\triangle OFG \sim \triangle EFJ~$ we have

$$|FJ| = |FE| \cdot \frac{|FJ|}{|FE|} = |FE| \cdot \frac{|FG|}{|FO|} = 2r \cdot \frac{r}{R-r} \\
\implies |BC| = 2r \Bigl( 1+\frac{r}{R-r} \Bigr) \qquad \text{, with}~~|BC| = 6$$

Solve for $r$ with $R = \dfrac{25}3$ obtained above, we arrive at $r = \dfrac{75}{34} \approx 2.206$.
[image]
<sup>Note that point $E$ being the center of the small circle on the right, is different from midpoint of $\overline{PC}$ point $Q$ in the previous diagram (not shown here).</sup>

$$\begin{aligned}
2r \Bigl( 1+\frac{r}{R-r} \Bigr) = 6 \quad &\implies r+\frac{r^2}{R-r}  = 3\\
&\implies rR -r^2 + r^2  = 3R-3r \\
&\implies r(R+3)  = 3R \\
&\implies r= \frac{3R}{3+R} = \frac{3 \cdot 25/3}{3+25/3}  = \frac{75}{34}
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: No, I believe you now.  I just wonder where I went wrong.  Or maybe the wolfram solver I used messed up.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

\begin{align}
R^2&=|AH|^2-|HO|^2=\tfrac{a^2}4+(R-b)^2
,\\
R&=\frac{a^2+4\,b^2}{8\,b}
=
\frac{25}3
,\\
|HE|&=|HK|+|KO_0|+|O_0E|
,\\
b&=r_0+\sqrt{4\,r_0^2-((R-r_0)^2-(R-b+r_0)^2 )}+r_0
,\\
r_0&=\frac{R\,b}{2\,R+b}
=\frac b2\cdot\frac{(a^2+4\,b^2)}{a^2+8\,b^2}
=\frac{75}{34}
\approx 2.20588
.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

If the white curve is a circle the you have three points of the big circle (assume symmetry: Big circle has $(-8,0),(0,6),(8,0)$) so the equation (and radius) can be figured.

Big Circle is center at $(0, -A)$ with radius $R$ and $8^2 + A^2 = R^2$ and $0^2 + (A+8)^2 = R^2$.

The three little circles have equations $(a_i - x)^2 + (b_i-y)^2 = r^2$.  $a_1=-a_3;b_1=b_3; a_2 = 0$. circle 1: has the three points $(-w,0), (-v,z);$ (which satisfies $v^2 + (z+A)^2 = R^2$) and $(-m,k)$.

Circle 2: has three point $(-m,k),(m,k)$ and $(0,6)$.  The point $(-m,k)$ shared between circle 1 and circle two is tangent and colinear to the centers.

And circle 3 has three points $(w,0),(v,z),(m,k)$.The point $(m,k)$ shared between circle 1 and circle two is tangent and colinear to the centers.

So solve the following equations.

Big Circle:

$(8-0)^2 + (0+A)^2 = R^2$

$(0-0)^2 + (6 + A)^2 = R^2$

$(m-0)^2 + (k+A)^2 = R^2$

$(v-0)^2 + (z+A)62 = R^2$

Circle 2:

$(m-0)^2 + (k-b_2)^2 = (0-0)^2 + (6-b_2)^2 = r^2$.

Circle 3:

$(a_3-w)^2 + (b_3-0)^2 = (a_3 - v)^2 + (b_3 - z)^2=(a_3-m)^2 + (b_3-k)^2 = r^2$

Colinear tangent of circle 2 and circle 3

$m = \frac {a_3}2$ and $k = \frac {b_2 + b_3}2$.

Comment: Minus the first two equations, this is a system involving $11$ variables. However this system is of the form $P=Q=R,\,S=T=U=V,\,W=X.$ This gives at most $10$ equations, so that a unique solution is not yet guaranteed.

Comment: They aren't linear and they have restrictions on being positive.  And if there are not a unique solution then....  oh.. you are right the finally equation is that the centers of the 2nd and 3rd circle and the tangent point are colinear.